# Eloquent prepares query but does not execute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 'customer' table and I am trying to get a record using Laravel Eloquent using the customer's id:

```
Customer::where('customer_id', '=', $customer_id)->get();
```

However, when this gets executed I check the MySQL logs and I get:

```
Prepare select `kanji_name` from `customer` where `customer_id` = ?
Close stmt
Quit
```

As you can see, there is no 'Execute ...' log which should be present of the query was executed after preparing it.

I also tried:

```
Customer::find($customer_id);
```

with the same result.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes I did. See my answer.
On my development environment, I disabled MySQL cache so I always get the Execute log. That made it easier for me to check what parameters were actually sent to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some form of caching that is happening either on the Eloquent side or MySQL side (possibly on MySQL side).

I restarted my MySQL server and found that on my first try, I get

```
Prepare select * from `customer` where `customer_id` = ?
Execute select * from `customer` where `customer_id` = '4058'
Close stmt
Quit
```

While on succeeding tries, I get:

```
Prepare select * from `customer` where `customer_id` = ?
Close stmt
Quit
```

only.

Answer (score 0):

can you do this

```
$cust = Customer::where('customer_id', '=', $customer_id)->get();
dd($cust);
```

Sorry, not enugh reps to comment. What's DD output?

Comment: It prints the Eloquent object. However, that is not what I was looking for. I'm looking for the missing Execute login my MySQL log.