# Eloquent query will only prepare, not execute

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, prepared-statement

This is for Laravel 5.2. My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719506/eloquent-prepares-query-but-does-not-execute) question. Basically, I'm trying to run a query that was suggested to me in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856456/using-a-laravel-model-method-in-an-eloquent-query), which returns data when it actually executes:

```
>>> App\Models\User::whereRaw('CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%?%"', ['test'])->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#769
     all: [],
   }
```

This is what the mysql log shows:

```
Prepare   select * from `users` where CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%?%" and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
Close stmt
```

---

However, this statement works:

```
>>> App\Models\User::whereRaw('CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%test%"')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#770
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#767
         id: 1,
         name_first: "test",
         name_middle: null,
         name_last: "user",
         email: "test@test.com",
       },
     ],
   }
```

And the associated mysql log entries:

```
Prepare   select * from `users` where CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%test%" and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
Execute   select * from `users` where CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%test%" and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
Close stmt
```

Any information or advice about why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a small problem there (which was from my solution on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35856557/351330)). When you use this:

```
User::whereRaw('CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%?%"', ['test']);
```

The resulting SQL query string will be this (after the binding would be applied):

```
select * from `users` where CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE "%'test'%" and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Since the value quoted would be `test` you'd end up with `"%'test'%"` which will match nothing. To fix that you should move the wildcard characters into the bindings array like so:

```
 User::whereRaw('CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE ?', ['%' . $value . '%']);
```

Now the value would be quoted correctly:

```
select * from `users` where CONCAT(name_first, " ", name_last) LIKE '%test%' and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

There is also the alternative of using `DB::raw` for places where you specifically want the parameter passed to the Query Builder to not be escaped. So in this case you could use the regular `where` like so:

```
User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ', email)"), 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
```

That will make sure the concatenation part will not be escaped.

Comment: After putting the wildcards in the bindings array, everything worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't think to try that on my own. I'm still confused why the statement was never executed even if the wrong value would have been used, though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. I've fixed my answer to your previous question as well :).